# Fetch unique record from database from multiple option

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have table name: **goal**

```
id  date        valueweekmodified           goal_type_id    user_id
1   2016-01-07  2   1   2016-01-07 16:21:56 3   3
2   2016-01-07  5   1   2016-01-07 16:21:56 1   3
3   2016-01-07  0   1   2016-01-07 17:17:01 3   4
4   2016-01-07  500 1   2016-01-07 17:17:01 1   4
5   2016-01-07  0   1   2016-01-07 17:50:11 3   6
6   2016-01-07  300 1   2016-01-07 17:50:11 1   6
7   2016-01-07  1   1   2016-01-07 17:52:40 3   5
```

I want to fetch those users who had set the only and only goal_type_id=3.

For Example:
see id 1,2.  That record should not be returned because user_id=3 has two goal_type_id=1 and 3.

From above table only id=7 is valid, because only that row contains goal_type_id = 3 (for user_id=5). Rest of all user had set two goal which I don't want.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select user_id from goal 
where user_id not in (select user_id from goal where goal_type_id !=3)
and goal_type_id = 3;
```

for the whole row

```
select * from goal 
where user_id not in (select user_id from goal where goal_type_id !=3)
and goal_type_id = 3;
```

or

```
select id,  date, value, week,modified,   goal_type_id ,user_id
from goal 
where user_id not in (select user_id from goal where goal_type_id !=3)
and goal_type_id = 3;
```

Comment: I want the whole row instead of user_id

Comment: Actually, Your solution is right But I have one question. If I remove the "and goal_type_id=3" still it is giving me same output. My question is Is there any specific reason behind putting this (and goal_type_id=3) condition.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, My point is just to confirm reason behind this condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id
from goal
group by user_id
having bool_and(goal_type_id = 3)
```

`bool_and` returns *true if all input values are true, otherwise false*

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE

Comment: I want the whole row instead of user_id